# react-burger-menu css does not work

Tags: reactjs

I'm using burger-menu and i can't set CSS for the burger menu like the author guide: https://github.com/negomi/react-burger-menu

Here's my burger menu component:

```
import React from 'react';

import BurgerMenu from 'react-burger-menu';

import { List, ListItem, ListItemContent } from 'react-mdl';


var MenuWrap = React.createClass({

    getInitialState() {
        return {hidden : false};
    },

    toggle() {
        this.setState({hidden: !this.state.hidden});
    },

    render() {

        let style;

        if (this.state.hidden) {
            style = {display: 'none'};
        }

        return (
            <div style={style} className={this.props.side}>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
});

export default class LeftSidebar extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            currentMenu: 'push',
            side: 'left',
            hidden: true,
        };
    };

    render() {
        const Menu = BurgerMenu[this.state.currentMenu];
        var styles = {
            bmBurgerButton: {
                position: 'fixed',
                width: '36px',
                height: '30px',
                left: '36px',
                top: '36px'
            },
            bmBurgerBars: {
                background: '#373a47'
            },
            bmCrossButton: {
                height: '24px',
                width: '24px'
            },
            bmCross: {
                background: '#bdc3c7'
            },
            bmMenu: {
                background: '#373a47',
                padding: '2.5em 1.5em 0',
                fontSize: '1.15em'
            },
            bmMorphShape: {
                fill: '#373a47'
            },
            bmItemList: {
                color: '#b8b7ad',
                padding: '0.8em'
            },
            bmOverlay: {
                background: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)'
            }
        };


        return (
            <MenuWrap wait={20}>

                <Menu
                    style={styles}
                    noOverlay id={this.state.currentMenu}
                    pageWrapId={'page-wrap'}
                    outerContainerId={'outer-container'}
                >
                    {console.log(Menu)}
                    <List>
                        <ListItem>
                            <ListItemContent icon="person">Dashboard</ListItemContent>
                        </ListItem>
                        <ListItem>
                            <ListItemContent icon="person">Community</ListItemContent>
                        </ListItem>
                        <ListItem>
                            <ListItemContent icon="person">About</ListItemContent>
                        </ListItem>
                    </List>
                </Menu>
            </MenuWrap>
        );
    }
};
```

And here is my main component:

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './Main.scss';

import LeftSidebar from '../LeftSidebar/LeftSidebar'

export default class Program extends React.Component {
  render() {
      return (
      <div id="outer-container" style={{height: '100%'}}>
        <LeftSidebar />
        <div id="page-wrap">
          <p>Content</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

All of the css from variable styles does not work.

EDIT: the problem above is solved by change style ={styles} to styles = {styles}. The other problem is: when i click  close, the sidebar menu shift down about 10 or 20px before moving back to the left. How to remove that shift down effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you have a typo. It should be `styles={styles}` instead of `style={styles}`.

Comment: OMG thank you! I treated it as React inline CSS but i was wrong!

Comment: Then the other problem is when i click  close, the sidebar menu shift down about 10 or 20px before moving back to the left. How to remove that shift down effect?

Comment: That's a CSS issue. Try playing with some of the properties like `top` or the margins. Otherwise set up a JSFiddle so that we can help you further.

Comment: Is there anyway we could hide the toggle switch and only programmatically toggle the menu?