# ReactJs using styles css module on react-burger-menu component

Tags: reactjs

I am working with [react-burger-menu](https://github.com/negomi/react-burger-menu) and I am having trouble setting the `styles={styles}` tag on the menu component, from a CSS module.

Given :

#### ./App.js

```
import Page from './components/Page/Page';
import SideMenu from './components/sideMenu/SideMenu.js';
import styles from './components/sideMenu/SideMenu.module.css';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app" id="app">
      <SideMenu styles={ styles } pageWrapId={ "page-wrap" } outerContainerId={ "app" }/>

      <div id="page-wrap">
        <Page />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


export default App;
```

#### ./sideMenu/SideMenu.js

```
import React from "react";
import { scaleRotate as Menu } from "react-burger-menu";


export default props => {
  return (
    <Menu {...props} >
      <a className="menu-item" href="/">
        Home
      </a>
    </Menu>
  );
};
```

#### ./sideMenu/SideMenu.module.css

```
.bm-burger-button {
  position: fixed;
  width: 36px;
  height: 30px;
  right: 36px;
  top: 36px;
}

.bm-burger-bars {
  background: #373a47;
}
```

I am unable to pass the prop `styles` to `SideMenu` menu bar. The stylesheet is just not read. I have also tried `style={styles}` instead. If I omit the `styles={styles}` tag and just put the CSS styling in `./index.css` then the styling is rendered correctly but I want to separate the menu styling as a module.

I have also tried to write the

```
import styles from '../../components/sideMenu/SideMenu.module.css'
```

inside the `sideMenu/SideMenu.js` file instead, and `return (<Menu {...props} styles={styles}> (...)` but still with no success.

Finally, I have also tried to set

```
<div className="app" id="app" styles={styles}> (...) </div>
```

in `./App.js` as it was suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40025313/react-burger-menu-css-does-not-work) but that doesn't work either.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

1. First, it’s recommend to use camelCase for classes with more than one word. The reason for this is that you’ll access these classes later as properties of a JS object, hyphens are not syntactically allowed. So you must first of all change your `SideMenu.module.css` for example like this:

```
.bm_burger_button {
  position: fixed;
  width: 36px;
  height: 30px;
  right: 36px;
  top: 36px;
}

.bm_burger_bars {
  background: #373a47;
}
```

2. Import the module you’ve just created from within your component, like you did:

```
import styles from './components/sideMenu/SideMenu.module.css';
```

3. To use a class defined in your module, just refer to it as a normal property from the styles object, like:

```
<div className={styles.bm_burger_button}> (...) </div>
```